# Did the holy prophet Muhammad SAW recite this supplication/dua?

Tags: hadith, dua

Is the following dua proven have a history in hadith? I mean if there is a record that the holy prophet SAW used to or ever recited this dua given here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dua is from the Quran, so of course the Prophet (SAW) would recite it. It is a Sunnah of the Prophet Musa (AS) was made by him when he was told by Allah to go on a mission to Firaun:

> قَالَ رَبِّ ٱشۡرَحۡ لِى صَدۡرِى (٢٥) وَيَسِّرۡ لِىٓ أَمۡرِى (٢٦) وَٱحۡلُلۡ عُقۡدَةً۬ مِّن لِّسَانِى (٢٧) يَفۡقَهُواْ قَوۡلِى -٢٨
>
> He said, ‘My Lord! Open my breast for me. Make my affair easy for me. Remove the knot from my tongue, [so that] they may understand my discourse. (20:25-28)

Since, the dua works well for many situations, it is often used. The dua also continues, but it is too specifically related to Musa (AS) so this part isn't usually used by people:

> Appoint for me a minister from my family, Haroon, my brother. Strengthen my back through him, and make him my associate in my affair, so that we may glorify You greatly, and remember You greatly. Indeed You see us best.’ (20:29-35)

Comment: Subhan Allah. May Allah give you reward. Ameen